# Vector space and axioms

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms

How would i go around proving a(u+v)+ u= (a+1)u+av  using axioms?
I started with distributivity with respect to vector addition, associativity of addition, commutativity of addition, distributivity with respect to field addition. I think i am missing one axiom.

Comment: What are these objects? If you mean $a$ is a field element and $u,v$ are in some vector space, then this is usually false since the LHS is $au+av$ and the RHS is $au+av+u$, so unless $u=\mathbf{0}$ you're SOL.

Comment: Now you are right

Comment: @AdamHughes changed it now

Comment: Sure i haven't missed one.

Answer (score 0):

distributive law says $(a+1)\mathbf{u}=a\mathbf{u}+1\cdot \mathbf{u}$. Identity law says that $1\cdot \mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$.

As such you see that

> $$(a+1)\mathbf{u}+a\mathbf{v}=(a\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u})+a\mathbf{v}$$
>   $$=a\mathbf{u}+(\mathbf{u}+a\mathbf{v}) = a\mathbf{u}+(a\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u})$$
>   $$=(a\mathbf{u}+a\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{u} =a(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{u}$$